# Editing a post when there is already an edit waiting for review

Tags: discussion

I was just attempting to edit a post where there was already an edit waiting to be reviewed.

When I clicked on the edit button, it asked me to review the edit.

**Is it not possible to edit a post when there is already an edit waiting for review?**

Comment: Exact even the people with above 3k get to approve or reject the edit instead of being able to edit it.

Comment: @Videonauth - So all the edits I see you make with the comment "made the image visible"  are made using the "improve edit" option?

Comment: @Videonauth - That didn't make much sense.

Comment: No not all edits i make are made that way, in fact only a few are. Up to that i only can approve/reject edits only 20 times a day. That is the limit all of us have. Beside what shall i write if i exactly did this only made an image visible. Sure if I see typos I flatten them as well while doing that.

Comment: @Videonauth - No offense, but if you're running for mod, I would expect that you double check your grammar before posting :)

Comment: Noted and I will try to improve on that, English isn't my native tongue tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three choices here.

1. Reject their edit and do your own (I guess this is what you want in the question).
2. Improve their edit, they still get the rep but you can make adjustments.
3. Just accept their edit.

If you don't like their edit, reject it, say why and do your own. This, to me, is just the same as ignoring their edit and doing your own.

If you accept their edit, then there should be no reason for you to make another edit.

If you improve it, it will be implemented instantly and have your name on it.

Comment: Well I guess the edits that happened on this answer here is the perfect example why you have to reject/accept an edit before making your own.

Comment: @Dan sorry that i rolled back your edit, it was mainly because Mark posted some more to his edit and your edit made those lines disappear.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Although you spelled "their" as "there". I fixed it for you though :)

Comment: It kept getting edited and edited, spelling is not my forte, I looked it up though, you are right, this is the correct usage :) @AndroidDev

Comment: @MarkKirby - Is the spelling of "their" different in the U.K.?

Comment: No, it is just me, I can't spell to save my life, never could. Spell checkers don't help with grammatical errors though, I mess up my to and too quite often as well.

Comment: @MarkKirby - Too bad LibreOffice doesn't have MS Word's grammar checker.

Comment: I know it is like blasphemy here but that is one of the two reasons I still have a win partition, office (it is really, really good IMO ms office) and games. @AndroidDev

Comment: @MarkKirby - Yeah, I keep 7 for Office and Video/Photo editing software.